# How do I get my books on the iBook store?

Tags: books, apple-inc

How do I get my books on the iBook store?

Comment: Do you mean, how do you publish your own books on the iBook store?

Comment: @ThomasLHoladay -yes, but if I have it in iBook format (ePub or similar) then it is already technically an iBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [portal on iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/apply) which allows you to publish your books. [There is a bit of a writeup about the process here](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/05/27/apple-increases-support-for-self-publishing-in-ibookstore/).

Comment: How to upload a book on UK store not on US?